# Flink, Java class is treated as a POJO class or General class

Tags: apache-flink

I have a Java class that is used to store state:

```
public class Speed {
    public Speed() {}

    public Speed(double speed, Telemetry telemetry) {
        this.speed = speed;
        this.telemetry = telemetry;
    }

    public double speed;
    public Telemetry telemetry;
}
```

Telemetry is not a POJO class, and I provided a serde for it.

```
public class TelemetryKryoSerializer<T extends Telemetry> extends Serializer<T> {

    @Override
    public void write(Kryo kryo, Output output, T object) {
        byte[] bytes;

        TelemetryProto.Builder builder = object.toProtoBuilder();
        bytes = builder.build().toByteArray();
        output.writeInt(bytes.length);
        output.write(bytes);
    }

    @Override
    public T read(Kryo kryo, Input input, Class<T> type) {
        int l = input.readInt();
        byte[] bytes = input.readBytes(l);
        Telemetry telemetry = null;

        telemetry = Telemetry.parseFrom(bytes);
        return (T) telemetry;
    }
}
```

How can I confirm whether the above class is treated as a POJO class or General class?

Update:

I registered Telemetry class and it's serializer as follows:

```
env.getConfig().registerTypeWithKryoSerializer(DataElement.class, DataElementKryoSerializer.class);
```

Following are the output of the getRegistered* methods mentioned:

```
Registered Kryo types:
<NONE>

Registered Pojo types:
class a.b.c.Telemetry does not contain a getter for field telemetryProtoBuilder
class a.b.c.Telemetry does not contain a setter for field telemetryProtoBuilder
Class class a.b.c.Telemetry cannot be used as a POJO type because not all fields are valid POJO fields, and must be processed as GenericType. Please read the Flink documentation on "Data Types & Serialization" for details of the effect on performance.

TypeSerializer for Telemetry
org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.runtime.kryo.KryoSerializer
class a.b.c.Telemetry does not contain a getter for field telemetryProtoBuilder
class a.b.c.Telemetry does not contain a setter for field telemetryProtoBuilder
Class class a.b.c.Telemetry cannot be used as a POJO type because not all fields are valid POJO fields, and must be processed as GenericType. Please read the Flink documentation on "Data Types & Serialization" for details of the effect on performance.
```

Answer (score 0):

These are all helpful for debugging serialization issues:

- `ExecutionConfig#getDefaultKryoSerializerClasses()`
- `ExecutionConfig#getRegisteredKryoTypes()`
- `ExecutionConfig#getRegisteredPojoTypes()`
- `TypeInformation#of(MyClass.class).createSerializer()`

The last one will show you which serializer Flink is using for `MyClass`.

Comment: I updated my question with output of the methods you mentioned, very helpful.  The `TypeSerializer` for Telemetry is listed as `KryoSerializer` and the serializer I registered.  Can you please help me understand why?

Comment: What does it mean when a class cannot be used as a POJO type, and be processed as a GenericType. What are the implications?
And does it matter in this case, considering a de/serializer is provided?